# Why in Hamiltonian for hydrogen atom we have $\nabla_e$ and $\nabla_N$ and one does not operates on other?

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

Laplacian is $$\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial z^2} $$
Then why in Hamiltonian for hydrogen atom we have $\nabla_e^2$ and $\nabla_N^2$ and one does not operates on other ?

Comment: Please refrain from using mathjax in your title.

Comment: First, $\nabla$ is the del operator, the Laplacian is $\nabla^2$. Second, the mere existence of derivatives with respect to different variables does not imply that there should necessarily be mixed terms in each and every expression. For instance, the Hamiltonian does not contain any such mixed terms by its very definition: it consists of kinetic energy term plus potential energy one, where the first is additive.

Answer (score 4):

In quantum mechanics the Hamiltonian is commonly expressed as the sum of operators corresponding to the kinetic and potential energies of a system,
$$
\hat{H} = \hat{T} + \hat{V} \, ,
$$
where the kinetic part is additive, i.e., for an $n$-particle system
$$
\hat{T} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \hat{T}_{i} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} -\frac{\hbar ^2}{2 m_i} \nabla_i^2 \, .
$$
Thus, *by definition*, the Hamiltonian does not contain any mixed derivatives of $\nabla_i \nabla_j$ form.